# Inner join return duplicated record

Tags: join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My table:

| Report_Period | Entity | Tag | Users Count | Report_Period_M-1 | Report_Period_Q-1 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-06-30 | entity 1 | X | 471 | 2017-05-31 | 2017-03-31 | ... |
| 2020-12-31 | entity 2 | A | 135 | 2020-11-30 | 2020-09-30 | ... |
| 2020-11-30 | entity 3 | X | 402 | 2020-10-31 | 2020-08-31 | ... |

What I want:

| Report_Period | Entity | Tag | Users Count | Users_Count_M-1 | Users_Count_Q-1 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-06-30 | entity 1 | X | 471 | 450 | 438 | ... |
| 2020-12-31 | entity 2 | A | 135 | 122 | 118 | ... |
| 2020-11-30 | entity 3 | X | 402 | 380 | 380 | ... |

I have have tried this code but it duplicate records! How can I avoid it?

```
SELECT M."Entity",M."Tag",M."Report_Period",M."Users Count",
M."Report_Period_M-1",M1."Users Count" AS "Users Count M1",
FROM "DB"."SCHEMA"."PERIOD" M, "DB"."SCHEMA"."PERIOD" M1
WHERE M."Report_Period_M-1"= M1."Report_Period"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your join clause should include the entity column and tag (I suspect)

```
SELECT    M."Entity",
          M."Tag",
          M."Report_Period",
          M."Users Count",
          M."Report_Period_M-1",
          M1."Users Count" AS "Users Count M1",  
FROM      "DB"."SCHEMA"."PERIOD" M, 
         "DB"."SCHEMA"."PERIOD" M1 
WHERE    M."Report_Period_M-1"= M1."Report_Period"
AND      M."Entity" = M1."Entity"
AND      M."Tag" = M1."Tag"
```